# How to make a spiral staircase wrap around a cylinder that gets narrower as it gets higher

Tags: modifiers, shrinkwrap

I have made a spiral staircase and I am trying to get it to wrap around a cylinder that gets narrower as it gets higher.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I've tried to use the shrinkwrap tool but I am getting some really weird results.

Does anybody know of a good method to acheive this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A python script might be the most straightforward way to tackle this.

Comment: you could try a screw modifier

Comment: I might use a lattice deform to shrink the top of the stairs, though that may not provide exactly the results you’re looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind that the stairs lose a little width towards the top due to scaling, you can use the modifier `Simple Deform` for this.

[image]